# Open a form within the parent form-Not as separate screen in c#

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a parent form with a button and when in the click event of the button I want to open a new form.

```
Form2 form2= new Form2();
form2.Show();
```

But, form2 is opened as a separate process. I want the form to opened inside the parent form.

While googled I found out that MDI is being deprecated. So could you please suggest me a good way?

Comment: `MDI` is being deprecated in favor of `WPF`, if you use `winforms`, `MDI` is still useful. However the style of `MDI` is actually old.

Comment: It's not quite clear how you create `form2` as *as a separate process*. Do you really mean that?

Comment: @KingKing : I am using winforms.So how to use MDI??

Comment: @avo: form2 as a separate process means its showing as a separate screen.Not as a Form inside the main form

Comment: @Mothy Using `MDI` is simple, some search will lead you to more sample code. The most important properties you should look at are `MdiParent`, `MdiChildren` and to turn a form into a `MDI` form, just set `IsMdiContainer = true`.

Comment: @KingKing : could you please help me to achieve the above? I have written a code in the main form for moving the form in desktop.But when i made the parent form as IsMdiContainer = true, movable code of the parent form is not working and the child form is not showing up. :(

Comment: @Mothy I think you should ask a new question, remember to post your code, what you want and people here will help you.

Answer (score 4):

> While googled I found out that MDI is being deprecated

This is like Mark Twain's famous quote: "The reports of my death have been greatly exaggerated".  MDI is built into Windows, many old programs depend on it.  It has been around for over 25 years and is not going away anytime soon.

Programmers like to arbitrarily announce something deprecated when they don't like a feature.  Sure, nobody is that smitten with MDI.  That WPF didn't implement it doesn't make it deprecated, that would make shell notify icons deprecated too and they certainly are alive and well.  MDI was a windowing model that was invented to deal with the kind of monitors users had 25 years ago.  And 640 x 480 displays don't leave a lot of room for windows.  Finding a way to make overlapping windows manageable was its primary goal.

It doesn't make much sense to still use it on the gigantic monitors we have today.  Docking layouts are much more sensible.  Visual Studio being a good example.  You'll need to go shopping for a library that support it if you don't want to create one yourself.  Weifenluo's DockPanelSuite is very popular and has the right price.

Answer (score 2):

```
Form f = new Form();
f.TopLevel = false;
f.Visible = true;
Controls.Add(f);
```

[image]

Comment: I have tried the above code, the form is being added as a control, not as a window inside the main form

Comment: @Mothy I don't understand what you mean. What's the difference?

Comment: Form 2(child) inside form1(parent) like MDI .

Comment: Its being added as a control.Not opened as a window(child form) in the main form

Comment: What do you care what it's called? And by the way, a `Form` _is_ a `Control`.

Comment: Its being added as a "control",like we add controls to panel. Not as a separate window.

Comment: @Mothy Please explain what behavior you would like it to have that it doesn't now. You _can_ click on its controls. You _can_ move it. You _can_ resize it. You _cannot_ move it out of the parent-form (which seems to be what you're looking for, because if not - your original code already has that.)